# irregular sizes of images in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've an gallery with different size of images. Is there any solution to crop them during display?
I've tried to set style height: xxxpx but it looks awful (with width too). This images display from another sites, so I cant just download them and crop :(

Comment: Use `height` in css or html. The quality will depend on the resize filter the browser uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can crop an image by putting it inside an

```
overflow: hidden;
```

div.

Heres a JSFiddle example [Cropped Image](http://jsfiddle.net/F3kqY/), of course you wil probably want to use same javascript to centre/position the image and not simple setup magin numbers in the example I've done, but still it shows how to crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery plug-in that should do the trick:
http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set the width to a pixel measure in the html or the css and leave the height, or vice-versa, depending on whether you need them the same height or same width. Then they will be reduced but not distorted... obviously, if you need to crop to a set height *and* width, this won't work, but it *will* give you columns or rows that match in width or height.